# Html is leaving a blank space at the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css

I am doing a simple homepage with only HTML and CSS, and I have a problem that it shows too much space underneath that is not coming from any of the divs that I tested.

What could be causing it?

[image: example]

I tried to remove the negative top position and add a displa:flex to the main container but it did not help either.

Here is my code snippet:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'open-sans';
    src: url('/font/opensans-variablefont_wdthwght-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('/font/opensans-variablefont_wdthwght-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
*
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body {
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
}

.logo {
    width: 100%;
}

button {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    top: -45px;
    width: 222px;
    height: 35px;
    padding: 5px 14px 0 18px;
    background-color: #a2dc3c;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #a2dc3c 0%, #81b427 100%);
    border: none;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 700;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: open-sans, sans-serif;
}

.main {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.main-content {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: open-sans, sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    line-height: 30px;
}

a { color: #80b529 }


.content {
    margin-top: 30px;
}
.coy-logo {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-flex;
    max-width: 200px;
    top: -10px;
}

.tavarlin-logo {
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    height: auto;
    top: -50px;
    max-width: 180px;
}
.keto-logo {
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
    top: -50px;
    max-width: 140px;
}
.bottom-logos {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}
.footer-nav {
    width: 80%;
}

.footer-nav li {
    padding-inline: 4px;
}

.bottom-nav {
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: end;
    margin-top: 16px;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
}

h1 {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-size: 25px;
    line-height: 16px;
}
h2 {
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}
h4 {
    color: black;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

h5 {
    font-size: 16px;
}

p {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 24px;
}

li {
    padding-left: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.impressum-content {
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 24px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 22px;
    position: relative;
    width: 80%;
}
.impressum-content .footer-nav,
.datenschutz-content .footer-nav
{
    width: 100%;
}
.content-area {
    margin-top: 25px;
}
.datenschutz-content {
    font-size: 17px;
    display: block;
    line-height: 24px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-left: 22px;
    list-style-position: inside;
    width: 75%;
}
.datenschutz-text {
    margin-top: 25px;
}
hr {
    border-top: 1px solid #a2dc3c;
}
header.header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin-inline: auto;
}
/* Bigger screens */
@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
    .logo {
        transform: translate(0px, 30px);
    }

    .main-content {
        font-size: 24px;
        line-height: 50px;
    }

    .content {
        margin-top: 55px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

    .bottom-logos {
        position: relative;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        align-items: center;
    }

    .coy-logo {
        max-width: 400px;
        margin-top: -10px;
    }

    .tavarlin-logo {
        max-width: 328px;
        margin: 0;
    }

    .keto-logo {
        max-width: 300px;
    }
    button {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 400px;
        padding: 8px 12px 8px 12px;
        top: -15px;
        margin-bottom: 40px;
        background-color: #a2dc3c;
        background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #a2dc3c 0%, #81b427 100%);
        border: none;
        color: #fff;
        border-radius: 5px;
        position: relative;
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: 700;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-family: open-sans, sans-serif;
    }
}
/* Landscape */
@media screen and (min-width: 480px){
    .logo {
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: center;
        max-width: 320px;
        transform: translate(0px, 8px);
    }
    .img-container {
        display: inline-flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        margin: 0 40px;
        max-width: 800px;
    }
    button {
        top: -35px;
        width: 300px;
        height: 35px;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Nu Prevento</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/style.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class="main">
    <div class="main-content">
        <a href="https://www.gesundheitsmanufaktur.de/marken/nuprevento" target="_blank" rel="nofollow noopener">
            <img src="img/logonuprevento.png" alt="Nuprevento" class="logo">
        </a>
        <div class="btn-link">
            <form action="https://www.gesundheitsmanufaktur.de/marken/nuprevento" method="get">
                <button type="submit" formtarget="_blank">Produkte im Partnershop</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <p>Die Homepage der NuPrevento GmbH befindet sich in der Überarbeitung.</p>
        <p>
            Schreiben Sie uns bei Fragen oder Anregungen gern eine Mail an:
            <a href='mai&#108;&#116;o&#58;i&#110;%66&#111;&#64;&#110;u&#37;&#55;&#48;re%76&#101;n&#37;74o&#46;co%6&#68;'>
            inf&#111;&#64;nupr&#101;ve&#110;to&#46;co&#109;</a>
        </p>
        <p class="content">Besuchen Sie in der Zwischenzeit gern unsere Partnerwebseiten:</p>
        <div class="content">
            <a href="https://www.dr-coy.info/" target="_blank">
                <img src="img/logojohannescoy.png" class="coy-logo" alt="Johannes Coy">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom-logos">
            <a href="https://www.tavarlin.com/" target="_blank">
                <img src="img/logotavarlin.png" class="tavarlin-logo" alt="Tavarlin">
            </a>
            <a href="https://www.keto-drink.com/" target="_blank">
                <img src="img/ketodrink.svg" class="keto-logo" width="300" height="300" alt="Keto-Drink">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="footer-nav">
        <hr>
        <ul class="bottom-nav">
            <li><a href="impressum.html" target="_blank">Impressum</a></li>
            <li><a href="datenschutz.html" target="_blank">Datenschutzerklärung</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well the iPad continues for a while even if your website doesn't. I would work with a couple of spacers to even out the empty space. Or just give your `.main-content` a min-height for different media queries?

Comment: Do you expect the iPad to shrink physically while the user view your page? It's just empty space where you as developer didn't define how to use it. There are multiple ways to solve this if this is a problem to you. You can space the elements evenly, move just the footer to the bottom. Maybe discuss with your designer about what's best :)